# Include new page.php and die the rest of content

Tags: php, include, die

Is there any way to include a new page by GET function and die the rest content of the present page.

This is what I tried

```
if($_GET['send'] == '1') echo include("info.php");
{die('info');}
```

This code kills all the page but the warning message is coming up.
I want get that warning message after including the info.php which will be 
test.php?send=1

Comment: And what *is* the `warning message is coming up`?

Comment: sure it's {die('info');}

Comment: But once i run the code it kills the page

Comment: Yes `die()` will kill the page. So the question is what is the *warning* you are getting. Sounds like that either needs to be fixed. Is it that `$_GET['send']` is not defined? You tell me.

Comment: Dont see why the "warning" would go away on its own tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written the `if` makes it a one line conditional. This means the `die` runs on every load regardless if the condition matches or not. Put the `die` in the `if` and this should function as you want.

```
if($_GET['send'] == '1') {
    include "info.php";
    die('info');
}
```

Additionally, I would recommend not `echo`ing an `include`. Any `html` or PHP outputting will output as the file normally would.